# I have a bottle of unopened 23 year old corked spanish white cooking wine

Tags: wine, storage

with laurel leaves steeping in it as well. I bought it at the Placio De Espania in 1992. Would it still be safe for use?

Comment: cooking wine tends to be heavily salted ... so it probably didn't go to vinegar.  But if it did go to vinegar, it might still be useful as an ingredient.

Comment: That's an answer I'd upvote @Joe

Comment: As a point of terminology, "corked" is a term that means the wine has spoiled, ostensibly because the cork has failed by rotting or drying out. "Sealed with the original cork" is probably a better way of putting it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, barring something really bizarre, it is safe.

It probably sucks, but the best way to know for sure is to taste it.

Know one thing, it is not any more "aged" in a positive way now than it was 23 years ago. It's just older. For more information check out the Wiki, [Aging of Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aging_of_wine).

Comment: That's a line I'd like to use about myself: "I'm not _aged_, I'm just _older_."

Comment: @Erica Yes...that thought went through my mind too!